# Is there any way to download complete web page in windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

i am looking for way to download complete webpage for an windows store app. since windows.forms.webbrowser class cannot be used for windows store apps, i left with a choice of Http.HttpClient class but this method won't give the complete information of the web page. So is there any other way for this ????

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be specific about "*this method won't give the complete information of the web page*".

Comment: i was referring about  using httpclient. The htmlpage from httpclient will have less information compare to the the html information i get from actual browser.

Comment: "htmlpage from httpclient will have less information compare to the the html information i get from actual browser"  Such as?

Comment: the html page i got from httpclient will not be having associated images, JS and CSS.